# TableView (FX 2) of Simple data type

Tags: java, tableview, javafx, javafx-2

i want to make a tableView without making an object Row like the [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)
i just want it to reflect a simple 2D array like double[][] and if that is possible can it be editable

Answer (score 0):

Building a custom control that holds a double value, renders it, provides editing mode (through some action like on click), and putting these custom controls to some layout (GridPane, TilePane, FlowPane) should be more suitable in your case.

Comment: i need a table because the table supports sorting the data and some other features, actually a table is more suitable in my case

Comment: @leonardo_aly. If sorting the one column effects other columns as well, then there should be some "row object" structure to manage sorting easily. Otherwise if sorting effects only one column then again tableView may not fit your needs. Anyway sorting can be implemented manually in the mention solution above.